# Create a headless Remote Desktop connection

Tags: command-line, rdp, headless

I'm looking to automate deploying content via RDP.  The current setup involves manually RDPing to the machine, copying the file to it, and moving it into place.  Once on the remote machine, I can easily script massaging the content into place, but how do I script establishing the RDP session and kicking off the remote script?

Comment: Just to get the obvious out of the way, why not use SSH?  I'm sure you have a reason.  Do you need to push content out to a bunch of Windows machines that don't have SSH servers running?

Comment: Yes, the target servers are Windows boxen and don't have SSH running.

Comment: There is no public documentation for protocol, but there are non-Microsoft implementations of RDP (i.e. listed in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_Desktop_Protocol) - you may look into using or reviewing them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that Remote Desktop can only be used interatively.  Powershell Remoting seems to accomplish the goal though.